# program for watching a memory

Tags: memory, assembly, disassembly

Is there a freeware (or better open source) program (framework) for watching behavior of memory (in particular stack and registers) during activity of given program (process) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's called a debugger... Consider `gdb` for a free & open-source version. `gdb` also has many GUI wrappers for your convenience (if you're a GUI person).

In particular the `x` command in `gdb` lets you examine memory in powerful ways. Read more about it and other options in any `gdb` reference - I think you'll be happy with what you see.

Comment: But can I watch a memory trace with gdb during a real working of (for example multithreaded) program, which must intercommunicate with another processes (or network)?

Comment: @ninjaa: you can run any program with the debugger

Answer (score 1):

That is the job of pretty much any debugger you can find...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you weren't refering to the role of a debugger, there's a program called [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) which essentially is task manager on steroids.  It presents you with a list of processes and their threads as well as CPU and memory usage for each one.  Now that I've gotten used to it, I never use task manager.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

for the memory take a look at cachegrind...
if you are interested in the stack look at Zoom if you are on linux.
I recommend Zoom it has a free trial for 30 days